# dc.js - Ordering numerical bar chart

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I'm wondering whether there is a clever way to arbitrarily sort my groups in a numerical bar chart - I tried to redefine `.ordering()`, but the method is not called. Which makes sense, since you want your numerical data usually naturally sorted.

My goal is to sort my bar chart e. g. by the group values instead of the group keys. I can imagine just returning a sort index in my chart's `.keyAccessor()` - is there a more direct method, like enabling `.ordering()` for numerical bar charts?

Thanks!

Comment: You're right, it wouldn't make much sense to order the items when the X scale is quantitative. If you're willing to forgo brushing and only pick individual items for filtering, an easy way to enable `.ordering()` is to use an ordinal scale.